# Im using weebly and want a box to popup when the user hovers over some text

Tags: html, css, popup, hover

I'm using Weebly and want a box to popup when the user hovers over specific text, giving them more detail about the specific word. Can I do this in weebly or is there code I can add.

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe add apps into weebly from their appstore, but you also use this:

```html
<style>
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
.tooltip .tooltiptext {
    width: 120px;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 50%; 
    margin-left: -60px;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
}
</style>

<center>
 <br><br>
 <div class="tooltip">Word
  <span class="tooltiptext">More words</span>
 </div>
</center>
```

Just copy the whole thing and change "Word" and "More words". If you want the popup box to be someplace else let me know.

Comment: Thanks I will give it a go

Comment: @MattTyrrell No problem

Comment: @MattTyrrell Place it wherever you want the text to be.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: @MattTyrrell No problem